# Error when compiling on g++

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

For my project I'm required to compile my program on both Microsoft Visual Studios (windows) and g++ (unix).

My program works when on windows, but when on g++ I get the following error:

```
utilities.cpp:4:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory 
#include <windows.h>
```

I feel like I messed up when separating the header file and utilities.cpp.

For reference here is the globals.h and the utilities.cpp files:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmSpr.jpg

Comment: Uhhm, you are compiling under linux and trying to include a file called "windows.h" - guess where the error is^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `<windows.h>` on a linux machine

Use `ifdef` to choose what preprocessor commands run. More specifically, you can check if the operating system is windows with the pre-defined `__WINDOWS__` macro. Most compilers

```
#ifdef __WINDOWS__ 
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

You can also try `_WIN32`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your compilation failure has been explained by @NickLamp , but only that macro won't make your program work properly in Xnix.

It seems that you are building CLI interface, and instead of using OS-specific APIs, I recommend you use some cross-platform CLI libraries:
Cygwin + ncurses or pdcurse.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o for details.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the Java, C and C++ are not platform independent languages. Some of their things like - libraries files, pre-defined objects and functions may vary from one Operating System to another.

If you want to compile your file on **Ubuntu**, then you will have to either remove the `<windows.h>` header file from your file or use some techniques (*like - macros*) which ensure against the use of `<windows.h>` on the Operating Systems other than Windows. Because this header-file is strictly designed for Windows.